# How to send every file from repo to instance?

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Currently I have JenkinsFile which is supposed to push the repo to "production" instance if it's master branch or "stage" instance otherwise.

```
    if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){
            stage('Release to PRD') {
                    sh '''
                    ???
                    '''
            }
    } else {
            stage('Release to STG') {
                    sh '''
                    ???
                    '''
            }
    }
```

}

I've been searching "Jenkins Syntax" from Jenkins portal but I can't find the one.

Is there any way to...

- **push/update the code to an instance**

OR

- **trigger `git pull` the repo from the instance?**

Possible Solutions I have

1. Jenkins has a special(?) command to push the code to prod instance.
2. Jenkins somehow accesses to the instance and call `git pull`. << This seems more reasonable? // Further I can do tagging as well :D

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the push event from your repo to Jenkins, you have to configure that thru the repo's webhook. For github, repo --> settings tab --> add webhook (your jenkins' url) --> click "Just the push event". On the Jenkins side, jenkins job --> build triggers --> "Poll SCM" and input how mins you want jenkins to scan the repo for any push events.

Comment: how "mins"?? not sure what you meant

Comment: NO this is not what I need. Poll SCM is to update code in Jenkins instance NOT production instance.